# Shell script "current_id: command not found" error

Tags: bash, sh

When I run my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read NUM

case $NUM in
    1)
        current_id = "$$"
        ps -ef > file1.txt

        echo "$current_id"
        while [ $current_id -ne 1 ]
        do 
            current_id =$( cat file1.txt | awk '(if ( $s == '$current_id' ) print $3;)')
            echo " | "
            echo " v "
            echo $current_id
        done

        echo "";;
```

I get the error:

```
current_id: command not found

[: -ne: unary operator expected
```

I am trying to find the child-parent tree with this method. Is there something wrong with my syntax? Or is the current_id = "$$" not allowed? Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In assignment, there must not be a space before `=`

```
current_id =$(...)   # tries to run a program called current_id, which does not exist
current_id=$(...)    # assigns a value to variable
```

Comment: That seemed to fix the "current_id: command not found", however the        [: -ne: unary operator expected error is still lingering. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @pr68: Try putting an extra set of `[` `]` around your while statement. (eg.`while [[ $current_id -ne 1 ]]`)

Comment: @I'L'I I found the issue my if statement needed to go from ` '(if ( $s == '$current_id' ) print $3;)') ` to `'{ if ( $2 == '$current_id' ) print $3;}')`. Thanks for the help.